# How to make height in CSS responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a html like bellow and I want it to work like if the height of `content-1` is `480px`, the `content-2` will follow the height of the `content-1`. My width is just working fine but my height doesn't follow.

How to do it in css?

```css
  .container{
     clear: both;
    }
    .content-1{
     width:66.66%;
     position: static;
     background-image: url("../images/path1");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
    }

    .content-2{
     width:33.33%;
     position: static;
     background-image: url("../images/path2");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="content-1"></div>
       <div class="content-2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ..aaand container is like 100% height? I mean.. what means *"will follow the height of"*?

Comment: can you show your css code also.

Comment: your 2 inner `div` is not closed. You're saying that you want `content-2` to have the same height of `content-1`?

Comment: What if you adjusted the height of the container and just make the content divs 50% height? Not exactly an answer but an alternative.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
 
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
 
  margin-top: 10px;
 
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
 word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-container">
   <div class="content-1 flex-item">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
   <div class="content-2 flex-item">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping a code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who don't have much coding experience.

Comment: Now let's use some more properties. Consider a list of 6 items, all with a fixed dimensions in a matter of aesthetics but they could be auto-sized. We want them to be evenly and nicely distributed on the horizontal axis so that when we resize the browser, everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

Close your `internal div tags`. You can set height for your `parent div` i.e. `.container:480px` as below and `child element` take that automatically as `100%`. (or) Use jQuery to get height of `.content-1` and set that for `.content-2`

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(".container > .content-1").css("height");
    $(".container > .content-2").css({
    height : height,
    background : "#f22"
     });
    });
```

```css
    .container{
    width:100%;
    height:480px;
    }
    
    .container > .content-1{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
    
    .container > .content-2{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="content-1"></div>
       <div class="content-2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not an good approach to achieve responsive height using script's. Since there are many way to achieve this using CSS.

Comment: @VivekVikranth Well yes, but this to is a option among those. Whereas flex works perfect in this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
.container {
    display: table;
}
.content-1, .content-2 {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: you missing a dot before `content-2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS3 Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) in this case. `container` class will have `display:flex` and all your child class will set to same height.

```css
.container {
  display:flex; 
 
}

.content-1 {
  border:1px solid #000000;
  width:50%;
   height:480px;
  }

.content-2 {
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content-1">Content 1</div>
   <div class="content-2">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `display:flex;` do?

Comment: It enables a flex context. It align and distribute space among items in a container. Read more on Flexbox here: [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try using display table :

```
.container { 
    display: table;
    height: 480px;
 }
.content-1 {
    display:table-cell;
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content-2 {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you need add more 1 class to that:

```css
.height{
  height: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content-1 height">
   <div class="content-2 height">
</div>
```